# Normalize JSON and Remove Duplicated Data

Tags: json, pandas

I am hoping someone can assist me as I am new to pandas

I have a JSON which I am attempting to convert into an HTML Table.  As I understand it, pandas should be the best for this (if not - feel free to suggest alternatives).

So I have this JSON

```
{
    "Projects": [
        {
            "Name": "Project1",
            "Code": "111111",
            "BillingCode": "76893",
            "Department": "Department1",
            "Accounts": [
                {
                    "id": "123456",
                    "name": "account1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "648925",
                    "name": "account2"
                }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Project2",
            "Code": "222222",
            "BillingCode": "29214",
            "Department": "Department2",
            "Accounts": [
                {
                    "id": "333333",
                    "name": "account3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "444444",
                    "name": "account4"
                }
             ]
        }
    ]
}

df_accts = pd.json_normalize(data=d['Projects'], record_path='Accounts', meta=['Name','Code','BillingCode','Department'])
df_accts.head()
print(df_accts)
```

```
   id      name      Name    Code BillingCode   Department
```

0  123456  account1  Project1  111111       76893  Department1
1  648925  account2  Project1  111111       76893  Department1
2  333333  account3  Project2  222222       29214  Department2
3  444444  account4  Project2  222222       29214  Department2

As you can see this generates the data table correctly. What I would like to figure out is how to remove the duplication such that the data is grouped by the Project 'Name'
Ideally with the result being (this is manually done)

```
Name    Code BillingCode   Department
Project1  111111       76893  Department1
     id      name
  1  123456  account1
  2  648925  account2  
Project2  222222       29214  Department2
  3  333333  account3  
  4  444444  account4
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want a text format as output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want text as output, you could use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
cols = ['Name', 'Code', 'BillingCode', 'Department']
other = df_accts.columns.difference(cols)

print('\t'.join(cols))
for k, g in df_accts.groupby(cols)[other]:
    print('\t'.join(k))
    print(g)
```

*If you want to save to a file, you can replace the `print` by a call to `write` or [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) in append mode.*

Output:

```
Name    Code    BillingCode Department
Project1    111111  76893   Department1
       id      name
0  123456  account1
1  648925  account2
Project2    222222  29214   Department2
       id      name
2  333333  account3
3  444444  account4
```

Comment: Thank you!  Wow that was fast!
That certainly helps.
My goal at the end of the day is to produce an HTML Table

Comment: @DaveM can you clarify how? Then I'd suggest to use a template (for example with [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/)) you will be able to adapt this loop into it.